# Apple Home Kit - Server driven

Tags: homekit

Is it possible with Apple Home Kit and therefor Siri, to communicate with a server with intents rather than communicating with the device, like a light, itself?

I would like to say "Siri turn on the light in Room X", and the light fixture in the room to be controlled by a server, so the intent goes to the cloud rather than the light itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge) for that:

> Homebridge is a lightweight NodeJS server you can run on your home network that emulates the iOS HomeKit API

It works quite well. I use it, running on a Raspberry Pi, to control (from Siri and also from the *"Home"* app) a 433Mhz transmitter to control lights and other remote control devices in my home.

There are [a lot of plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=homebridge-plugin) that you can install to control devices, but it's also possible to [create your own plugins](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge#writing-plugins) to receive the intents and perform an action based on them.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I figured out as well. And it seems reasonable, that if you want to leave the home network, you need a hardware or software bridge. I'll leave the question open for some time, to see if anyone else have worked with it.

Comment: For the "outside world" bridging, I use a (relatively) old iPad that's tucked away somewhere. It's not doing anything else but act as the HomeKit hub, it basically channels all commands to Homebridge.